# Simplification of Kampé de Fériet function

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I was dealing with a convolution type integral
$$
\int^z_0 t^m {}_0F_1(;1;-t) \: {}_2F_3\Big( 1,1;2,m,m+1 ; -a t\Big) \:\mathrm{d}t
$$

By applying one of the identities in [Exton's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470263423), the solution should be
$$\frac{\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(m+1)}
z^m
\,
\mathrm{F}^{0:3;1}_{1:3;1} 
\Bigg(
\begin{matrix}
  - &:& m,1,1 &;1& \\ 
 m+1&:& 2,m,m+1&;1&
\end{matrix}
\Bigg|
-az,z
\Bigg)
$$

any idea how to reduce this form of Kampé de Fériet function into :

(a) a product of hypergeometric functions

(b) any form of Appell or Humbert series.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\int_0^zt^m~_0F_1(;1;-t)~_2F_3(1,1;2,m,m+1;-at)~dt$

$=\int_0^zt^m\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nt^n}{(n!)^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ka^kt^k}{(m)_k(m+1)_k(k+1)}dt$

$=\int_0^z\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}a^kt^{n+k+m}}{(n!)^2(m)_k(m+1)_k(k+1)}dt$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}a^kt^{n+k+m+1}}{(n!)^2(m)_k(m+1)_k(k+1)(n+k+m+1)}\right]_0^z$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}a^kz^{n+k+m+1}}{(n!)^2(m)_k(m+1)_k(k+1)(n+k+m+1)}$